# Can I develop an Asp.net Core 3.1 MVC app against existing DB with no scaffolding?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to move to Visual Studio for Mac (2019), I want to make a small asp.net core 3.1 mvc app that does CRUD on an existing database used by other apps. I do not want scaffolding or partial classes. And I really don't want migrations.

I would like to create the DbContext and models that match the three existing tables I want to use.

If this is possible, I would be very grateful for suggestions about how to inject the context and any other considerations. If there is an existing example, I'd be grateful for a link to that as well.

Comment: What is the question? If it's possible? and then you just want suggestions on injecting a context into .net core app?

Comment: @AbdulG the question is, if it's possible, then suggestions of how to inject context. Thank you.

Comment: Run scaffold, remove not needed tables from context. That's all. Or create model by the hands.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is no problem creating a context and models against an existing database with no migrations and no scaffolding or partial classes. You just need to write the models and context and Startup.cs injection code by hand.

I was intimidated by the dearth of instructions or examples, but had no reason to be.